# Android: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializer using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

I have an application that stores some data in `SharedPreferences`. This control data is synchronized with a server, and when the user logins in the application I retrieve it using an `AsyncTask`. I'm trying to store the data retrieved in `SharedPreferences` again, but I'm getting a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`.

This is the `AsyncTask` code:

```
public class RetrieveLogTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    private String errorMessage;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            String controlRow = NetworkUtilities.getData();

            if(controlRow != null){
                LogHandler.restoreControls(LoginActivity.this, controlRow);                 
                return true;                        
            }
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mRetrieveTask = null;

        if (success) {              
            createAccountAndFinish(true);
        } 
        else{
            Log.d("LoginActivity", errorMessage);
            askRetry();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mRetrieveTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

And this is the function in LogHandler class causing the error:

```
public static void restoreControls(Context ctx, String controlRow){
    String[] controls = controlRow.split(LogHandler.FILE_COLUMN_SEPARATOR_ESCAPED);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    editor.putString(TODService.PREFS_KEY_ARRAY_ICONTROLS, controlRow); // ERROR HERE

    editor.commit();
}
```

The line that causes the error is the `putString` call. controlRow is not null and not empty, and editor is not null.

This is the log output:

```
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at com.timeondriver.tod.log.LogHandler.restoreControls(LogHandler.java:835)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at com.timeondriver.tod.authenticate.LoginActivity$RetrieveLogTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:328)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at com.timeondriver.tod.authenticate.LoginActivity$RetrieveLogTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    ... 5 more
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at com.timeondriver.tod.TODService$1.<init>(TODService.java:513)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    at com.timeondriver.tod.TODService.<clinit>(TODService.java:513)
04-19 10:59:50.900: E/AndroidRuntime(16609):    ... 10 more
```

Anybody knows how to fix it??

Thanks!

[EDIT]

I add some code:

```
private void askRetry() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);

    alertDialogBuilder
    .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_error_retry))
    .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.message_error_retry))
    .setCancelable(false)

    .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.retry)
            ,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            mRetrieveTask = new RetrieveLogTask();
            mRetrieveTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    })

    .setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.alert_cancel)
            ,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            showProgress(false);    
        }
    })
    ; // Fin alertDialogBuilder

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();     
}

private void createAccountAndFinish(boolean logRetrieved){
    showProgress(false);

    // Create the local account.
    Account account = new Account(mPhone, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    Bundle user_data = new Bundle();
    try{
        mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, mPassword, user_data);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    // Set account's additional data and finish the activity.
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, mPhone);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_PASSWORD, mPassword);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, mAuthToken);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, true);
    LoginActivity.this.setAccountAuthenticatorResult(intent.getExtras());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    startActivity(i);
    LoginActivity.this.finish();
}
```

In TODService.java:513 there's a Handler declaration:

```
private static Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    ...
}
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: askRetry(); createAccountAndFinish(true); what these functions will do ?

Comment: What is on `TODService.java:513`?

Comment: I added askRetry() and createAccountAndFinish in the main post. IIn TODService.java:513 there's a Handler declaration (also added to the end of the post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ExceptionInInitializerError** - Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer. An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

Seems you are doing some stuff to Update your `UI` from a `Non-UI thread`. i.e., From Background worker thread

you must call this statement `LogHandler.restoreControls(LoginActivity.this, controlRow);` in `onPostExecute();`.

So your edited class must look like

```
public class RetrieveLogTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
{
    private String errorMessage;

    @Override
    protected Sring doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        String controlRow = null;
        try
        {
            controlRow = NetworkUtilities.getData();
        }
        catch ( AuthenticationException e )
        {
            errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            errorMessage = e.getMessage();
        }
        return controlRow;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String controlRow)
    {
        mRetrieveTask = null;
        if ( controlRow != null )
        {
            LogHandler.restoreControls(LoginActivity.this, controlRow);
            createAccountAndFinish(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("LoginActivity", errorMessage);
            askRetry();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled()
    {
        mRetrieveTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have said I was sure I didn't update my UI in doInBackground, but I tried what you said and it's working. Thanks you so much! :)

Comment: really you not updating the UI. You trying to create a handler using static initializer which reason for the ExceptionInInitializerError.